# JSTL <c:choose> does not recognize form input integers

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, jstl, servlet-3.0

I try to apply discount on checkout page based on user input. The user goes in his account and with a press of a button, he can apply a discount to his current purchase. On submit, he is being redirected to the checkout page where the discount is applied. It's just a form that sends information to another form.

I have several external javascript files that handle the discount function. I only call the script I need based on the condition with `c:choose`. The issue is, jstl does not recognize integers and treats any `input` that is being requested as a `null` value.It is always the first script, the `noDiscount.js` that is being executed no matter what is the `value` in input.

Could this bug due to incompatible data type? The script is looking for an integer while I'm sending it a string... How to get around this?

**userAccount.jsp**

```
<form method='POST' name='DiscountForm' action='applyDiscount'>

<input class="discount" readonly  name="discount" type="text" value="<%= resultset.getString("discount")%>"/>

<input type='submit' style="border:none; padding:1%; background:black; color:white; cursor:pointer;" value='Apply Discount'>

        </form>
```

**checkout.jsp**

```
<head>
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${discountValue == null}"><script type="text/javascript" src="js/noDiscount.js"></script></c:when>

   <c:when test="${discountValue == 10}"><script type="text/javascript" src="js/discount(10).js"></script></c:when>
</c:choose>

</head>


<body>
 <c:set var="discountValue" value="<%= request.getParameter("discount")%>"/>

                    <input class="discount" style="background:#eaeaea;" readonly id="userDiscount" name="applied_discount" type="text" value="${discountValue}"/>


</body>
```

**noDiscount.js** 
(regular sales tax calculator when no discount has been entered):

```
    function applyTax(){

  var cartSubTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).innerHTML);

  console.log(cartSubTotal);

  var salesTaxGst = (cartSubTotal / 100) * 5;
  var salesTaxPst =  (cartSubTotal / 100) * 9.975;

  var totalAmount = (cartSubTotal*1) + (salesTaxGst * 1) +(salesTaxPst * 1) ;

  document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).innerHTML = cartSubTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'taxGst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxGst.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'taxPst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxPst.toFixed(2);

        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'cartTotal' );
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].value = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
  }

    }

window.onload = function() {
  applyTax();
};
```

**discount(10).js**
    (apply 10% discount)

```
    function applyTax(){

  var userDiscount = parseFloat(document.getElementById( 'userDiscount' ).innerHTML); 
  var cartSubTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).innerHTML);

  console.log(userDiscount);
  console.log(cartSubTotal);

  var newDiscount = (cartSubTotal / 100) * 10;
  var salesTaxGst = (cartSubTotal / 100) * 5;
  var salesTaxPst =  (cartSubTotal / 100) * 9.975;




  var totalAmount = (cartSubTotal*1) - (newDiscount*1) + (salesTaxGst * 1) +(salesTaxPst * 1) ;

  document.getElementById('userDiscount').innerHTML = newDiscount.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).innerHTML = cartSubTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'taxGst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxGst.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'taxPst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxPst.toFixed(2);

        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'cartTotal' );
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].value = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
  }

    }

window.onload = function() {
  applyTax();
};
```

Comment: set the variable before you use it in `c:choose`,  So put line `<c:set var="discountValue" value="<%= request.getParameter("discount")%>"/>` before using the var in `c:choose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, even tho I find it less efficient, it works. I'm Using JSTL instead of Javascript to handle arithmetic:

```
<c:set var="PST" value="${(cart.subtotal / 100) * 5}"/>
<c:set var="GST" value="${(cart.subtotal / 100) * 9.975}"/>
<c:set var="discountValue" value="<%= request.getParameter("discount")%>"/>


<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${discountValue == null}">

       <c:set var="cartTotal" value="${cart.subtotal + PST + GST}"/>

   </c:when>

   <c:when test="${discountValue == 10}">
       <c:set var="disc10" value="${(cart.subtotal / 100) * 10}"/>

       <c:set var="cartTotal" value="${cart.subtotal - disc10 + PST + GST}"/>

   </c:when></:choose>
```